# How to rescue the Panel 0

Tags: panel

How can I recover `XFCE` the Panel 0?

I screwed up something here and now I don't know what to do: I erased the XFCE Panel 0 (the default-standard horizontal panel where are the typical application icons).

I can not to find a way to recover it, not in the Configuration Panel, not in the Menu Configuration.

How can I "rescue" it? Can I?

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!

Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recover the `xfce` default panel, go to `all settings` from the menu and choose `panel`.

Now at the top is a bar, it will be empty, click the `+` symbol under it to add a panel, then choose `backup and restore`

[image]

In the menu is a list, the default `XUbuntu` panel is `XUbuntu modern` click this and then hit apply in the bottom left (the little cog symbol)

[image]

This will restore the default `XUbuntu` panel.

Comment: "Unity"? ??? The "About" reference of "my" panels is: "xfce4-panel 4.12.0"

Comment: Your question does not say this, as  you don't say I assumed the default unity. See my update